# Why wheel spacers cause vibration

Tags: bmw, car

Just after getting very stoked on the visual improvement from my wheel spacers I get a steering vibration problem. Details:
Used nice H&R hub centric spacers on OEM 19s, 10mm rear, 15mm front
Carefully cleaned hub mounting surfaces with scotchbrite pads
Used new lengthened lug bolts
Lug bolts properly torqued to 88 ft lb

Result: Annoying rotational steering wheel vibration. A bit intermittent (i.e. NOT persistent) but clearly more noticeable, i.e. larger amplitude and occurs more often on more road surfaces.

Anyone else notice this? Any tips or solutions? By the way my tires are not heavily worn and the rest of the suspension, chassis are 100% stock.

Answer (score 3):

One source for this is that because you have moved the wheels relative to the hub, then this changes the loading on the bearings.

While they were ok in the standard situation, now that the loading has changed it may be that there is excessive "play" causing problems that you are now feeling. Have them checked.

Answer (score 1):

http://atvcarmotorcycle.blogspot.com/2017/11/the-main-reason-why-wheel-spacers-cause.html
In fact ,wheel spacers in themselves don’t cause vibration,they are just increasing the cars sensitivity to a pre-existing problem.Wheel spacers could be magnifying an existing imbalance or out-of-round condition in tires. Also, this may be incompatible with the natural frequency of the front control arm bushings. Most likely, though, is an amplified pre-existing problem.Anyway,a few causes lead to vibration.
Hope that helps.